# What do the two-letter object "values" mean in the Chrome debugger?

Tags: javascript, highcharts, google-chrome-devtools

I'm debugging some JavaScript using the HighCharts library and see these two-letter "values" for objects (`Fa`, `Rb`, `Fa` below). Expanding the object doesn't show anything that would hint to what the two-letter code means (see "counters" in the screenshot). Mousing over them shows the same cryptic two-letter code.

[image]

What do those two-letter things mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those are function names.

Javascript minifiers replace meaningful names with very short names to save bytes.